# Eclipse outputs java version in console instead of running program

Tags: java, eclipse, console, version, eclipse-kepler

Sometimes when I try to Run or Debug program several times in a row without changes Ecipse does nothing but outputs current Java version in console. Sometimes it works OK and I didn't find any correlation between my actions and its behavior. Any insignificant change in text helps, so this error is not serious but rather irritating. But anyway, do you have any idea why it happens?

Eclipse Kepler. Problem stays both for Java programs and C++ ones (via CDT).

Comment: Please add details on how others can reproduce this.

Comment: That is a pity, but I don't know. I've already written above, that I hadn't found exact cause. I hoped somebody faced the same problem. One thing: it seems to fail every time, when I launch project twice with focused "Problems" tab in editor. But there're several less predictable cases.

Comment: Sounds like your installation is broken.  Try with a fresh unzip of Eclipse without CDT and see if Java programs still fail